# Repeat simulation data and save the result as a matrix?

Tags: r, simulation

I want to simulate a mixture data and repeat it for many times. For each times I want to store data to use it later. For example:

```
         set.seed(123)
          N=1000
          U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
          X= matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=2)
          for (i in 1:N){
              if(U[i] < 0.8){
                  X[i,] <- rnorm(1,2.5,3)
                     } else {
                 X[i,] <- rnorm(1,2,1)
 }
  }
```

This will generate mixture data and store it as a matrix (X). My question, how can I repeat this simulation for say 100 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, however it is very straightforward. Use another "for" loop and save the results in a list.

```
runs = 100
Res = list()
for(k in 1:runs){
set.seed(123)
N=1000
U=runif(N, min=0,max=1)
X= matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:N){
  if(U[i] < 0.8){
    X[i,] <- rnorm(1,2.5,3)
  } else {
    X[i,] <- rnorm(1,2,1)
  }
}
Res[[k]] = X
}
```

The command

```
> Res[[1]]
```

will now give you the results of the first simulation.

Please note that by setting

```
set.seed(123)
```

inside the for loop, every simulation will yield exactely the same result.

Comment: Thank you E L M for your answer. Does that mean I can use each Res[[k]] as separate data. Because I would like to use this simulated data in another function. E.g.,   Myfunc -> EM(data=X).

Comment: Yes, every Res[[k]] element is a matrix and can be used further.